# Selecting the right dependent variable for regression

Tags: regression

I am new to statistics and starting a project to develop a set of probabilities for a horse race. I am using Stata with a database containing about 20 variables. One of the variables is finish position with values 1 for win and 0 for others. Would I use this as the dependent variable ? and does each race need a unique ID ?
Thanks
Ian

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes, your dependent variable should be the *thing* you're trying to predict. Setting a clear objective to your model will help you determine this. Since your project is about horse races, I'm assuming the objective of your model is to determine the winning horse for each race. In that case, your assumption is correct, the **finish position** variable would be your dependent. And considering your dependent variable is organized in a binary form (0 or 1's), you should also use the **logistic regression** for the best results.